# How to detect display resolution changes?

Tags: c#, resolution

I need to identify the changes of the display resolutions in run time.
This ([Keep track of screen change and screen resolution change in Windows Form Application to change form size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789414/keep-track-of-screen-change-and-screen-resolution-change-in-windows-form-applica)) helped me to trigger the event. But I am still unable to get new resolutions of the display.

Can it be achieved using `sender` and `e`?

Answer (score 2):

Just get the screen [`Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) from the screen itself:

```
Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds
```

Or iterate over [`Screen.AllScreens`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.allscreens(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all screens and their dimensions.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for?

Comment: No. I need to do it without iterating through  Screen.AllScreens. I mean within the event method itself.

Comment: Yes...of course... If a way cannot be found like using sender and e, it would be the answer.

Comment: There is no other way. The event handler just doesn't supply that information.

Comment: @AnoAPI any reason you unaccepted my answer? Need help?

Comment: @PatrickHofman - You could also use the `Screen.FromControl()` method to get the screen hosting a specific control, assuming that the OP is asking in order to resize something in response to display changes.

Comment: Indeed. Thanks for the suggestion @theB.